# Yii Framework 2.0 Rules Date Validator

Tags: php, date, yii, validation, yii2

I am using Yii Framework 2.0. I have a form with a text input field which is meant for a date. I have read the Yii Framework 2.0 about the **Class yii\validators\Validator** and known all the validator keys which can be used inside of the **rules()** method in a model class. When I use the **date** key as below, it does not validate anything. It means that I still can put some text in that input field and can post the form.

When I changed it into **boolean** or **email**, I could see that it validates very well when I put something wrong in the input field. How can I validate a date value inside of an input field with Yii Framework 2.0?

My rules() method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         [['inputfield_date'], 'required'],
         [['inputfield_date'], 'safe'],
         [['inputfield_date'], 'date'],
    ];
}
```

My view page:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
     <?= $form->field($model, 'inputfield_date')->textInput(); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: please post the code for your form in your view file, also the full rules array as you have it in your model...

Comment: I just edited my question with the code of the rules() method and the form inside of the view page. Hope you can help. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Any chance you have solved this issue? I'm having same issue

Answer (score 42):

Boy the Yii docs suck. They don't even give an example. Working from O'Connor's answer, this worked for me since I was assigning the value in `2015-09-11` format.

```
// Rule
[['event_date'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d']
// Assignment
$agkn->event_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

The [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#date) don't even specify where `format` or `timestampAttribute` came from, or how to use them. It doesn't even say what the heck `from_date` and `to_date` are. And most of all, *no examples*!

Comment: As with all documentation it helps to read it thoroughly. Yii docs do mention what the attributes are for in this part of the documentation https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#declaring-rules 

Remember, it is an open source project and you are able to contribute if you feel confused about a specific part of the documentation.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @Chloe. Given that the most familiar documentation for pretty much anyone using Yii is going to be the PHP documentation, by comparison the Yii documentation is poor, particularly in specifying how to actually use things.

Answer (score 11):

Working solution. My rules() method:

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
     [['inputfield_date'], 'required'],
     [['inputfield_date'], 'safe'],
     ['inputfield_date', 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-M-d H:m:s'],
   ];
}
```

My form in the view page:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
   <?= $form->field($model, 'inputfield_date')->textInput(); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My method in controller:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()):
        if($model->save()):
            // some other code here.....
        endif;
endif;
```

Note that the date format depends on how you define your date format input field. Note once again that this is not an AJAX validator. After clicking on the submit button, you will see the error message if you enter something else which is not a date.

Comment: I tried this no luck. same thing happens the dateValidator doesn't validate at all even after form submission

Answer (score 3):

You can validate for date like this from model rules

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['date_var'],'date', 'format'=>'d-m-yy'],
        [['from_date', 'to_date'], 'default', 'value' => null],
        [['from_date', 'to_date'], 'date'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure how it is in Yii2, but going out from Yii1 that had to look like this...

```
array('org_datetime', 'date', 'format'=>'yyyy-M-d H:m:s'),
```

(source: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh8)

...I'd say i'd have to look something like this in Yii2:

```
['shopping_date', 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-M-d H:m:s'],
```

Comment: I have done the same just like you would do, but it didn't validate anything with the above code sample. Note that I have configured the date format of my datepicker into 'Y-m-d'. Must it exactly be like your dateformat 'yyyy-M-d H:m:s' ?

Comment: no, this format was just an example, have a look through the Yii docs, you may want to start here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-formatconverter.html

Comment: Thank you, but it is not about the date format or how to convert one format to another. It is about 'date' validator which does not do his job.Your code sample should work, but it is not working. I assume that it is a bug in Yii Framework 2.0

Comment: I have just got it work. Your code is correct, but this one method needs to be called in the controller **$model->validate()**, which is omitted by Gii. With this method it will validate the input by the rules above, but it is not an AJAX validator. Can live with it.

Comment: you may want to add it as an answer, that is allowed... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, date validation relies on $model->validate(), so does not work inline but is only triggered by clicking Save (i.e. it's typically applied in actionCreate/actionUpdate).

Secondly, it's applied *after* other rules like 'required', and *only* if they pass, so even when you click Save, if anything else fails validation, those errors will show, but the date error will not.

In summary, date validation can only be tested by ensuring that all other rules pass and then clicking Save.