# Yii2 DatePicker and DataBase

Tags: database, datepicker, phpmyadmin, yii2

I'm trying to safe a date from DatePicker in my database. But I have this error:

```
array(1) { ["date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(81) "Неверный формат значения «Дата выполнения»." } }
```

Неверный формат значения «Дата выполнения» translates Wrong format of the value
Дата выполнения - it's the name of the label.

```
if($model->validate() && $model->save()){

                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }else{
                echo $model->date;
                var_dump($model->errors);

            }
```

The code above is a part of my controller code. Before this condition I check if `$model` got the date or not. It gets. But these two `$model->validate() && $model->save()` give me `false`.

This is my form:

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Дата выполнения'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'autoclose'=>true
        ]
    ]);?>
```

And this is a part of my model code:

```
 public function rules()
    {

        return [
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['user_id'], 'integer'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['for_user_id'],'integer'],
            [['date'],'date']
        ];
    }
```

View.php:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'title',
            'description:ntext',
            'user_id',
            'for_user_id',
            'date:date',
        ],
    ]);

        ?>
```

Comment: I am still waiting. I need your answers, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use DatePicker I usually set the rule of the date as 'safe'.

Additionally, I found a similar question in Stack overflow found here [Yii Framework 2.0 Rules Date Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088435/yii-framework-2-0-rules-date-validator)

Which it's answers may help you.
Let me know!

EDIT:

I think you have to add the format parameter to the rule of you date attribute in the model. like this:

[['date'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d']

And be sure that the format 'php:Y-m-d' matchs the one you specified in the DatePicker

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! `[['date'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d']`. It helped

Comment: Great! Happy coding